# How to save the lines of grep matches?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a grep like this:

```
iarr=`grep -Poh '.*INPUT' file.txt`
oarr=`grep -Poh '.*OUTPUT' file.txt`
```

So with this content of file.txt:

```
INPUT  hello.txt
OUTPUT stack.txt
INPUT  stack.txt
OUTPUT hello.txt
INPUT  overflow.txt
OUTPUT overflow.txt
OUTPUT byebye.txt
INPUT  byebye.txt
INPUT  nick.txt
OUTPUT jesus.txt
```

Te output would be:

iarr

```
INPUT hello.txt
INPUT stack.txt
INPUT overflow.txt
INPUT byebye.txt
INPUT nick.txt
```

oarr

```
OUTPUT stack.txt
OUTPUT hello.txt
OUTPUT overflow.txt
OUTPUT byebye.txt
OUTPUT jesus.txt
```

Well, but I want to know what filenames I need in input and what will be the output, I mean:

- If a INPUT file has an OUTPUT (of the same file) in the lines bellow of the actual line, then this item would be deleted from the oarr.
- If a OUTPUT file has an INPUT (of the same file) in the lines above of the actual line, then this item would be deleted from iarr.

With these conditions, the result would be the following:

iarr

```
INPUT hello.txt
INPUT overflow.txt
INPUT nick.txt
```

oarr

```
OUTPUT stack.txt
OUTPUT byebye.txt
OUTPUT jesus.txt
```

I'm trying to get this result, but I don't know how to store the line of an especific match of the regexp in the grep command... This is what i thought to solve this, do you have another idea to do it?
May be reading it line by line...

Comment: Given your requirements, I don't understand your output. "byebye" has the same index in both arrays. Why is it removed from iarr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you only need the first occurrence of each filename. You can achieve this using awk:

```
awk '!x[$2]++' file.txt
```

will thus give

```
INPUT  hello.txt
OUTPUT stack.txt
INPUT  overflow.txt
OUTPUT byebye.txt
INPUT  nick.txt
OUTPUT jesus.txt
```

on which you can continue your processing.

Comment: @JohnDoe paste code in your question window not here. Also why  have to use a complex regexp? when same thing done by simple `awk`.

Comment: @JohnDoe have read again your question but i think you don't know what is your requirement.why you try mixing `grep` and `awk` if `awk` do your job.

Comment: @JohnDoe Also try `awk '!x[$2]++' file.txt | sort -u` command to get same pattern line with each other

Comment: I repeat: the data of the file and the first greps are only for the example. The file contains another data, wich is loaded with the two greps that I put at the end of the post. And I want to do the same thing yo did with the example: get only first ocurrence between two greps. Sorry, is little hard to explain.

Comment: @JohnDoe can you post file data?