# Save only the first occurrence in a merge of two greps?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "INPUT"
echo 

# Grep array 1
grep -v '.*SYSTSIN' input.txt | grep -oPh '(?!.*?\.tmp)[^|]+\|\s+\K[^|]+(?=\|\s+OK.*?\[INPUT)' |  uniq -i |
while read file; do
    echo "$file"
done

echo
echo "OUTPUT"
echo 

# Greap array 2
grep -Poh '(?!.*?\.tmp)[^|]+\|\s+\K[^|]+(?=\|\s+OK.*?\[OUTPUT)' input.txt | uniq -i |
while read file; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

With this is content in input.txt file:

```
 234234 |  robert.txt| OK|  INFO| [INPUT]
  54656 |   maria.txt| OK|  INFO| [OUTPUT]
 078978 |   maria.txt| OK|  INFO| [INPUT]
      8 |  robert.txt| OK|  INFO| [OUTPUT]
     57 |   steve.txt| OK|  INFO| [INPUT]
    567 |   steve.txt| OK|  INFO| [OUTPUT]
  09832 |   marta.txt| OK|  INFO| [OUTPUT]
     99 |   marta.txt| OK|  INFO| [INPUT]
    ASD |    nick.txt| OK|  INFO| [INPUT]
    RFE |   jesus.txt| OK|  INFO| [OUTPUT]
```

Te result printed is:

```
INPUT

robert.txt
maria.txt
steve.txt
marta.txt
nick.txt

OUTPUT

maria.txt
robert.txt
steve.txt
marta.txt
jesus.txt
```

Now I'm trying to go is get only the first occurrence of each filename and save it in the corresponding array. 
I mean: if a match is saved in one of the two arrays, all the matches of this filename which are below, will be ignored.

With these conditions, the result that I'm looking for is:

```
INPUT

robert.txt
steve.txt
nick.txt

OUTPUT

maria.txt
marta.txt
jesus.txt
```

Could I do it with `awk` command? Do you have another idea to do it? May be reading it line by line?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066388/how-to-save-the-lines-of-grep-matches)?

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can construct an associative array with each file associated with is first data ("input" or "output"):

```
awk -F"|" '{if(result[$2]==""){result[$2]=$5}} END{for(file in result){print result[file] file}}' input.txt|sort
```

This one liner give you this output:

```
[INPUT]    nick.txt
[INPUT]   steve.txt
[INPUT]  robert.txt
[OUTPUT]   jesus.txt
[OUTPUT]   maria.txt
[OUTPUT]   marta.txt
```

And you can work on this data.

Comment: Thanks! But it does not exclude the files with .tmp extension, and with an ".*SYSTSIN" at the begining of the line. Could i manage these conditions directly in the awk? Could you identate the code, please? Thanks!

Comment: You have two way to do this: with a grep before the awk call or with some tests on the parameters on the main awk loop. for the indentation you have to write this into an awk script, and not doing this inline. I will see if I can find some time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give me an example of how can I manage the result given in your awk, please? And another question: Imagine I save grep command in a variable, could I pass it to the awk instead of input.txt? :)